# how to use comparevalidator on textbox and boundfield item in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview

Hi I have a gridview with an asp boundfield named "OrderedQty" and an asp textbox (txtDeliveredQty) where user inputs the number of delivered quantity. How do I put a validation that refrains the user to input an number (integer) lower than the OrderedQty using comparevalidator?

Below is my code with this filteredvalidator:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Qty" HeaderText="Ordered" SortExpression="Qty"></asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delivered Qty">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewQty" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="100" TextMode="Number" Min="1"></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid number" ControlToValidate="txtNewQty" MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="100" SetFocusOnError="true" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Control To Compare on range validator

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" 
ControlToValidate="txtDeliveredQty" 
ControlToCompare="OrderedQty" Operator="LessThan" Type="Integer" 
ErrorMessage="The first number should be smaller than the second number!"  
Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
```